# How to make the data in my html table insert automatically with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, web

Here is my code. There is the http server (second code).
And the script to create the html with data from a database.

My problem is that when I launch my NodeJS app everything is fine. But when I go to read it displays the table. But if I update the database the table does not update.

Does anyone have a solution? Thanks

**Note**: I'm not interested in the answer with express because I try to learn how it works.

```js
var querystring = require('querystring');
var mysql = require('mysql2');

//Connection mysql
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "Nodejs",
    password: "NodeJS_MySQL",
});
//fonction mysql
con.query('SELECT * FROM customers.customers', function (err, rows) {
    if (err) throw err;
    querystring.stringify(rows);
        exports.read_content = function compose_html () {return'<!Doctype html>' +
                                '<html lang="fr">' +
                                    '<head>' +
                                        '<title>Read</title>' +
                                        '<meta charset="utf-8">' +
                                        '<style>'+
                                        'html{' +
                                        'font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;' +
                                        '}' +
                                        'a{' +
                                        'color:cornflowerblue' +
                                        '}' +
                                        'table {' +
                                        'border-collapse: collapse;' +
                                        'width: 100%;' +
                                        '}' +
                                        'th, td {' +
                                        'padding: 8px;' +
                                        'text-align: left;' +
                                        'border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;' +
                                        '}' +
                                        '</style>' +
                                    '</head>' +
                                    '<header>' +
                                        '<h1>Read</h1>' +
                                        '<a href="/">Accueil</a>' +
                                        '<br>'+ 
                                        '</header>' +
                                        '<body>' +
                                        '<table>' +
                                        '<tr>' +
                                        '<th>id</th>' +
                                        '<th>name</th>' +
                                        '<th>email</th>' +
                                        '</tr>' +
                                        rows.map(function(rows) {
                                            return '<tr>' +
                                            '<td>' + rows.id + '</td>' +
                                            '<td>' + rows.name + '</td>' +
                                            '<td>' + rows.email + '</td>' +
                                            '</tr>'; 
                                        }).join('')+
                                        '</table>' +
                                    '</body>' +
                                '</html>';
                            }
});
```

```js
//modules
var http        = require('http');
var fs          = require('fs');
var url         = require('url');
var path        = require('path');
var mysql       = require('mysql2');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var { parse }   = require('querystring');
var read_html = require ('./read_html.js');

//Conection mysql
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "Nodejs",
    password: "NodeJS_MySQL",
});

//serveur http
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) { 
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    // switch des chemins pour afficher les pages
    switch (path) {  
        case '/':  
            fs.readFile("page/index.html", function(error, data) {  
                if (error) {  
                    response.writeHead(404);  
                    response.write(error);  
                    response.end();  
                } else {
                    response.writeHead(200, {  
                        'Content-Type': 'text/html'  
                    });  
                    response.write(data);  
                    response.end(); 
                }  
            });
        break;
        case '/post.html':  
            fs.readFile("page/post.html", function(error, data) {  
                if (error) {  
                    response.writeHead(404);  
                    response.write(error);  
                    response.end();  
                } else {
                    response.writeHead(200, {  
                        'Content-Type': 'text/html'  
                    });  
                    response.write(data);  
                    response.end(); 
                }  
            });
        break;

        case '/read.html': 
                response.writeHead(200, { 
                    'Content-Type': 'text/html'  
                });
                response.write(read_html.read_content());  
                response.end(); 
        break;
        default:  
        response.writeHead(404, {  
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'  
        });  
        response.write('<html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head><body style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><svg enable-background="new 0 0 32 32" height="128px" id="Layer_1" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="128px" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><g id="Error_x2C__lost_x2C__no_page_x2C__not_found"><g><g><g><circle cx="7.5" cy="5.5" fill="#263238" r="0.5"/><circle cx="5.5" cy="5.5" fill="#263238" r="0.5"/><circle cx="3.5" cy="5.5" fill="#263238" r="0.5"/><path d="M30.5,8h-29C1.224,8,1,7.776,1,7.5S1.224,7,1.5,7h29C30.776,7,31,7.224,31,7.5S30.776,8,30.5,8z" fill="#263238"/><path d="M29.5,29h-27C1.673,29,1,28.327,1,27.5v-23C1,3.673,1.673,3,2.5,3h27C30.327,3,31,3.673,31,4.5v23      C31,28.327,30.327,29,29.5,29z M2.5,4C2.224,4,2,4.225,2,4.5v23C2,27.775,2.224,28,2.5,28h27c0.276,0,0.5-0.225,0.5-0.5v-23      C30,4.225,29.776,4,29.5,4H2.5z" fill="#263238"/></g></g></g><g><path d="M24.5,24c-0.276,0-0.5-0.224-0.5-0.5V21h-3.5c-0.163,0-0.315-0.079-0.409-0.212s-0.117-0.303-0.062-0.456    l2.5-7C22.6,13.133,22.789,13,23,13h1.5c0.276,0,0.5,0.224,0.5,0.5V20h0.5c0.276,0,0.5,0.224,0.5,0.5S25.776,21,25.5,21H25v2.5    C25,23.776,24.776,24,24.5,24z M21.209,20H24v-6h-0.647L21.209,20z" fill="#263238"/><path d="M10.5,24c-0.276,0-0.5-0.224-0.5-0.5V21H6.5c-0.163,0-0.315-0.079-0.409-0.212s-0.117-0.303-0.062-0.456    l2.5-7C8.6,13.133,8.789,13,9,13h1.5c0.276,0,0.5,0.224,0.5,0.5V20h0.5c0.276,0,0.5,0.224,0.5,0.5S11.776,21,11.5,21H11v2.5    C11,23.776,10.776,24,10.5,24z M7.209,20H10v-6H9.353L7.209,20z" fill="#263238"/><path d="M17.5,24h-3c-0.827,0-1.5-0.673-1.5-1.5v-8c0-0.827,0.673-1.5,1.5-1.5h3c0.827,0,1.5,0.673,1.5,1.5v8    C19,23.327,18.327,24,17.5,24z M14.5,14c-0.276,0-0.5,0.225-0.5,0.5v8c0,0.275,0.224,0.5,0.5,0.5h3c0.276,0,0.5-0.225,0.5-0.5v-8    c0-0.275-0.224-0.5-0.5-0.5H14.5z" fill="#263238"/></g></g></svg><h3>Oups cette page n&#39existe pas...</h3><a href="/">Page principale</a></body></html>');  
        response.end();
        break;
    } 
    //Collecter les données du formulaire POST et les insert dans la db
    if (request.method == 'POST') {
        var body = '';
        request.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
        });
        request.on('end', function () {
            var post = querystring.parse(body);
            con.connect(function(err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                //function query db mysql de post data
                var sqlpost = "INSERT INTO customers.customers (name,email) VALUES ('"+post.name+"','"+post.email+"')";
                console.log(sqlpost);
                con.query(sqlpost, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });
            });
        });
    }
});server.listen(8080);
// Fin du serveur http
```